# Array with Objects into xml

Tags: php, xml

im new here, and i hope someone can help me...
Ive got an Array, which Looks like this. I Needs this in a document, with all the objects in it.
The Problem is, that the Array is mixed with Objects. 
The Array should look like this:

```
<markers>
  <marker e10="1.279" e5="1.299" diesel="1.089" place="Illertissen" postCode="89257" houseNumber="19" adress="Saumweg" lng="10.10018" lat="48.23068" name="V-Markt Illertissen"/>
<marker e10="1.259" e5="1.279" diesel="1.069" place="Senden" postCode="89250" houseNumber="50" adress="Ulmer Str." lng="10.03625" lat="48.32817" name="Tankstelle Möbel Inhofer"/>
```

```
$Umkreissuchedec =json_decode($Umkreissuche);
stdClass Object
(
    [ok] => 1

    [license] => CC BY 4.0 -  https://creativecommons.tankerkoenig.de
    [data] => MTS-K
    [status] => ok
    [stations] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 8dcb0636-a988-4e1a-aef1-9369e95fa644
                    [name] => Markenfreie TS EISENACH
                    [brand] => Markenfreie TS
                    [street] => KASSELER STR.
                    [place] => EISENACH
                    [lat] => 50.977776
                    [lng] => 10.304671
                    [dist] => 3.5
                    [diesel] => 1.209
                    [e5] => 1.429
                    [e10] => 1.409
                    [isOpen] => 
                    [houseNumber] => 9
                    [postCode] => 99817
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => e1a15081-2611-9107-e040-0b0a3dfe563c
                    [name] => Eisenach, Kasseler Str. 55
                    [brand] => HEM
                    [street] => Kasseler Str.
                    [place] => Eisenach
                    [lat] => 50.981205
                    [lng] => 10.301261
                    [dist] => 3.8
                    [diesel] => 1.149
                    [e5] => 1.369
                    [e10] => 1.349
                    [isOpen] => 
                    [houseNumber] => 55
                    [postCode] => 99817
                )
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Use `$Umkreissuchedec = json_decode($Umkreissuche, true);` - now everything is an array.